# REST services in Android Project

Tags: android, rest

I am currently working on an android project for students and I want your help.
I am planning to develop an Android app and a website. In the Android app students can login and use multiple features like manage their profile, save their class timings, set alarm for assignments etc etc.

Now, I want to create services in my project. I am planning to use **REST services**. Since I am new to android and the concept of REST is also new for me.
I am confused that should I use **ASP.NET and sql server**? OR should I use **PHP and MYSQL**?

My second question is that, I have to create services for student login and registration except that where else I have to create these services in my project. 
Any help will be appreciated. Thank you!.

Comment: You don't really have to care how the server is implemented. It doesn't matter if it's `C#` or `PHP` (use the one that better fits your skills), because you will use `Json` to comunicate between your mobile app(client) and the server. As a starting point for REST services, I would go with Retrofit, but Volley is also a nice alternative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I will suggest you to use google's firebase it will save you lots of development time and costs https://firebase.google.com/.
   Sse Firebase's API for the server communication, it will handle all of the sign in and more
2. I would make a small package with class per service most of the actions are easy to create and use here is a nice tutorial about services http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidServices/article.html

Good luck!

Comment: Consider using Django and Django REST Framework. It's my first choice if I need to rapidly prototype custom REST service for mobile app.

Comment: For REST sercices, have a look at Retrofit library : http://square.github.io/retrofit/

Comment: Thank you all for answering!

Comment: If my answer helped you please approve and up vote it